# Función que comprueba si los argumentos son str y los convierte a tupla

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

He realizado una función que, a partir de unos datos dados en el formato:

```
x = [((40, 50), 9.27), ((10, 20), 6.73), ((30, 40), 2.45), ((60, 70), 2.67), ((20, 30), 5.68), ((50, 60), 2.45)]
```

se ejecuta devolviendo un gráfico (x,y) donde el eje de abscisas está formado por los primeros elementos de cada tupla ((40, 50), (10, 20), (30, 40), (60, 70), (20, 30), (50, 60)) y el eje de ordenadas por los segundos elementos. Como ven, los datos de los primeros elementos de cada tupla representan los rangos de edad. Es necesario que, obviamente, la función reordene estos elementos para representarlos en la gráfica de manera ordenada.

Pues bien, mi problema viene cuando los datos a introducir están en el siguiente formato:

```
x = [('(40, 50)', 9.27), ('(10, 20)', 6.73), ('(30, 40)', 2.45), ('(60, 70)', 2.67), ('(20, 30)', 5.68), ('(50, 60)', 2.45)]
```

Necesito decirle a mi función que, **en el caso** de que los primeros elementos de la lista contengan una cadena ('(0, 14)') en lugar de una tupla, esta me las convierta a tupla, con el fin de poder ordenarlos para poder representarlos en la función de manera ordenada. He separado los datos de entrada con el fin de tener en una única variable los datos del rango de edad y he intentado, sin suerte, convertirlos a tupla con la siguiente función:

```
[eval(i) for i in x]
```

Espero haber planteado bien el problema, y gracias por vuestro tiempo!!

Comment: El primer item de cada tupla SIEMPRE es una cadena que se puede transformar a tupla?

Comment: Además, tu pregunta que relación tiene con la etiqueta python-requests?

Comment: Sí, el primer item de cada tupla siempre es una cadena transformable a tupla. Acabo de quitar la etiqueta de pythin-requests, no tiene nada que ver con ella.

Comment: `[(eval(t[0]), t[1]) for t in x]`

Comment: o más genérico, por si la primera tupla puede ser cadena o no, y por si cada tupla en x puede tener más de 2 elementos: `[(eval(str(primer)), *resto) for primer, *resto in x]`

Comment: Sí, he conseguido convertir los strings a tupla con la función `eval` , lo que no consigo decirle a la función es que en el caso de que los datos de la variable sean str, los convierta a tupla. Es decir la sentencia `if i in f == str(): ` ó `for i in f: if i in f == str()` me devuelve un error, entiendo que de sintaxis, pero no lo encuentro.

Comment: La solución de @abulafia es correcta. Qué estás intentando hacer con esa sentencia? Qué error te da?