# Función que devuelve una tupla si los argumentos son cadenas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Muy buenas:

Estoy intentando implementar una función que devuelva una tupla a partir de una entrada de datos en modo `str`. Es decir, si la entrada de datos es `x = ['(2, 8)', '(4, 9)', '(8, 23)', '(12, 9)']`, debería devolver de la siguiente forma: `x = [(2, 8), (4, 9), (8, 23), (12,9)]`

El código que estoy ejecutando es el siguiente:

```
def tuplas(f):
for i in f:
    if f[i] == str():
        f = [eval(i) for i in f]
    else:
        f = f
return f
```

Con este código me devuelve el siguiente error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`, la entrada de datos con la que he ejecutado esa función era `a = ["(8, 3)", "(8, 4)", "(8, 6)"]`

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Función que comprueba si los argumentos son str y los convierte a tupla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510195/funci%c3%b3n-que-comprueba-si-los-argumentos-son-str-y-los-convierte-a-tupla)

Comment: No es bueno que hagas 2 preguntas iguales, solo debes hacer 1 e ir modificandola para que quede clara

Answer (score 3):

En general no es buena práctica usar `eval()`, en este caso es inofensivo pero este trae grandes problemas de seguridad.

Te recomiendo *parsear* tu string y obtener los valores individuales.

Por ejemplo:

```
list_of_tuples = []
for element in tuples:
    string_without_parenthesis = element.strip(' ()')
    indivual_numbers_list = string_without_parenthesis.split(',')
    new_tuple = (int(indivual_numbers_list[0]), int(indivual_numbers_list[1]))
    list_of_tuples.append(new_tuple)
```

En este caso `tuples` es equivalente a `f` en tu función.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Por cierto, con `literal_eval` del módulo `asp` puedes evitar los problemas del `eval`.

Comment: Gracias Tomás, lo único que me falta es decirle a la función que ejecute eso solamente en el caso de que **el argumento sea una lista de cadenas**, es decir, el código debería ser algo parecido a: `if f[i] == str():` pero cuando ejecuto eso, me sale error.. alguna sugerencia? Gracias de nuevo por la aportación

Comment: Prueba con `f[i] == str` o `f[i] is str` en vez de `str()`

Comment: Nada, me salta el siguiente error: `name 'i' is not defined`

Comment: Revisa los nombres de las variables en tu código, `i`debería ser la el nombre de la variable del primer término en el for loop.

Comment: @nautiluss999 debes  obtener el tipo de dato, realiza `if type(f[0])==str` antes de cualquier ciclo, o tambien podrías hacer `if all(type(c)==str for c in f)`

Comment: Gracias!! Todo arreglado.

Answer (score 3):

Podrías usar el método `literal_eval` del módulo `ast` y hacer lo siguiente:

```
# Importamos el módulo
import ast

def format_tuple(string_tuples: list) -> list:
    # Usamos literal_eval para lanzar una excepción si el tipo de dato es erróneo y de esta manera el código no será ejecutado si no lo es:
    return [ast.literal_eval(string_tuple) for string_tuple in string_tuples]

x = ['(2, 8)', '(4, 9)', '(8, 23)', '(12, 9)']

print(format_tuple(x))
```

Resultado:

```
[(2, 8), (4, 9), (8, 23), (12, 9)]
```

Si ves el tipo de dato:

```
for tupla in format_tuple(x):
    print(tupla, type(tupla), sep="\n")
```

Verás que devuelve tupla por c/u de ellas:

```
(2, 8)
<class 'tuple'>
(4, 9)
<class 'tuple'>
(8, 23)
<class 'tuple'>
(12, 9)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Gracias Adrián!!  lo único que me falta es decirle a la función que ejecute eso solamente en el caso de que el argumento sea una lista de cadenas, es decir, el código debería ser algo parecido a: if f[i] == str(): pero cuando ejecuto eso, me sale el error de que `name 'i' is not defined`.. alguna sugerencia de como poder corregirlo?